# Linkable preview of Google Docs (Sheets, Slides, etc.)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

Is there a way to get a live preview image (an image, similar to the content of the document that updates without manual intervention) of a Google Sheet (or other apps in the Google suite) to link to from another site?

My specific use case is that I have a Google Sheet that I'd like to include a preview of in a Markdown document on GitHub. My first thought was to use something like `<iframe src="sharing URL of the document">`, but GitHub renders that as the source code, not as the Google Sheet in an iframe. I could use a screen capture of the Sheet, but I'd like to have an image that "updated itself" when the document changes. The update need not be realtime, once a day or so would be just fine.

Comment: By editing your question [you change it quite a bit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/135278/2). It is customary to let people who already answered know about these changes by leaving a comment under the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of that.  

That said, I didn't think I was changing the question – I had already explained the use case and that GitHub did not render the ```iframe``` so I was looking for another way to show a preview of the document.

Comment: Please have a look at my new answer. There may be a workaround. Sorry about the downvote. It was only to attract your attention. Please edit (with whatever your question so I can change the vote. _"(You last voted on this question 6 hours ago. **Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited**.  )"_

Answer (score 1):

### **Iframes are not allowed in GitHub**

As stated on the GitHub site [here](https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension-) and [here](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks), **iframes are not allowed in GitHub**

**There may be a workaround though through Zap** (may be because I haven't tried it myself).

[image]

**Once you create your Zap account you get to see quite a few triggers**.

[image: github]

**Please give it a try and let us know how it goes.**

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by *"a live preview image"*?
On most sites you can usually have either an iframe or an embedded image or a link to it. But it all depends on the site and not the source of the image (unless hot linking is disabled).
In any case you can get the [shareable link like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_IB1mLqHUcc2JyTGlTaS1YNDg) of a google file by:

**- Right-clicking on the file**

[image: right-clicking]

**- or clicking on either of the options given on the top right corner of the folder**

[image: share a Google file]

*Unless of cource we are talking about [NASA Live: Earth Views from the Space Station](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szQSx4XYMoI) which actually is a video*.

Comment: Responded to your comment on the question.